# Unity XR InputDevice Characteristics always None for Oculus Quest

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, device, characteristics, oculusquest

I am using the latest XR Interactive Toolkit in 2019.3.

I have an XR Rig in my game with the left and right hand XR Controllers.

I have a script of my own that I am looking at the XR controller InputDevice characteristics member to try to determine which hand the controller is.

The characteristics member is always None. Here is some of my code:

```
        var characteristics = InputDeviceCharacteristics.HeldInHand | InputDeviceCharacteristics.Left;
        bool leftHand = ((_controller.inputDevice.characteristics & characteristics) == characteristics);

        Debug.Log(string.Format("is left hand: {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", leftHand, _controller.inputDevice.characteristics, InputDeviceCharacteristics.HeldInHand, InputDeviceCharacteristics.Left));
```

The output for both controllers is: false, None, HeldInHand, Left

Is this a bug or is there something I need to do to prime it or get the characteristics to populate?

Answer (score 0):

Quest controllers will not be recognized as HeldInHand.  You can use:

```
List<InputDevice> allDevices = new List<InputDevice>();
InputDevices.GetDevices(allDevices);
```

You get 3 devices - Quest, Left and Right Controllers.
Then use a .contains filter to separate left and right controller inputs:

```
if (device.name.Contains("Right"))
            {device.TryGetFeatureValue(CommonUsages.primary2DAxis, out localRightPrimaryAxis);
}
```